# How to avoid jQuery Operation Conflict with 2+ templates In Single-Page Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, singlepage

I build a Single-Page Application for ERP-like system with MVVM

there is one template A which include JQ operations like $("#xxx") ,some JQ pluigns like bootsrap modal and fineuploader also need attribute id to locate its modal and sub-template,

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="inline btn" data-toggle="modal">Select</a><br>
<!-- bootstrap modal use #id to find its modal template -->
```

Now I want to load template A twice (A1,A2) in one-page 'index.html',however I suffer JQ operation conflict ($("#xxx") in A1 return elements in A1 and A2 ,but I only need that in A1)

So,How to seperate A1 and A2 when I use Jquery?!

[it's a good idea to use $(#id.class) for find element outside(index.html) not template inside(JQ operations are in A) because A1,A2 templates share the same $(#id.class) and finally return two JQ objects. also using template engineer lead to difficulty of debugging this template because it's a complicated page]

Comment: Should probably share some code, yeah ?

Comment: @naomik added bootstrap modal HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single page cant have any two elements with same id, like #xxx. Use class instead of id.

```
<div class="xxx">A</div>
```

EDIT:
If you cant simply change id to class, you could use some [js template](http://underscorejs.org/#template)  to generate a dynamic id or a dynamic data-target.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes

```
<!-- dynamic id -->
<a href="#myModal<%= count %>" data-toggle="modal">Select</a>
<div id="myModal<%= count %>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">...</div>

<!-- dynamic data-target -->
<a data-target"myModal<%= count %>" data-toggle="modal">Select</a>
<div class="modal fade myModal<%= count %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">...</div>
```

Comment: it's a good idea to use $(#id.class) for find element outside not template inside because A1,A2 templates share the same $(#id.class) and finally return two JQ objects.also using template engineer lead to difficulty of debugging this template because it's a complicated page